# Как и каким интерфейсом сделать опросник?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

У меня есть проект питон и мне его надо перебросить в *Qt Designer*.

Как и каким интерфейсом это сделать?

Также какие блоки использовать в *Qt Designer* для создания именно такого опросника так сказать?

Мой код:

```
books = ["Математика", "Литература", "Музыка"]
book = input("Учебник: ")
if book in books:
print("Он там!")
else :
print("Он не там!")

answer = ["Да", "Ага"]
answer2 = input("Ты пойдёшь в школу? ")
if answer2 in answer:
print("Хорошо, не забудь она в 8:30")
else:
    answer1 = ["Заболел"]
    ans = input("A что так? Заболел или прогулял? ")
    if ans in answer1:
        print("Выздоравливай")
    else:
        print("А ну ка быстро иди! ")
```

Comment: код питон 3.7.4)

Answer (score 1):

Пройдите на tproger.ru: https://tproger.ru/translations/python-gui-pyqt/

Этого материала по созданию простого приложения с использованием qt-designer'а
более чем достаточно. Во всяком случае, ваш проект легко переносится на форму.

Если хотите автоматизировать такие процессы в дальнейшем нарабатывайте собственную библиотеку шаблонов.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш проект перебросить никуда не получится. Все надо создавать с нуля.
С целью дальнейшего вашего развития, создан пример демонстрирующий одну из возможностей создания опросников.

**PyQt** — набор `привязок` графического фреймворка **Qt** для языка программирования **Python**, 
выполненный в виде расширения Python.

**Qt Designer** — кроссплатформенная свободная среда для разработки графических интерфейсов 
программ использующих библиотеку Qt. Входит в состав **Qt framework**.

Установка PyQt5:

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

После инсталляции PyQt5, копируете модули `main_survey.py` , `survey_ui.py` и `survey_ui.ui` 
в какой-нибудь каталог.

Запускаем с консоли:

```
python main_survey.py
```

Для получения результатов опросника нажимаем на кнопку `Опубликовать результат опроса`.

`main_survey.py` - основной модуль приложения, содержит импорт класса `Ui_Form` из модуля `survey_ui.py` и логику программы.

`survey_ui.py` - модуль содержащий **дизайн** приложения, который был получен путем конвертации модуля `survey_ui.ui` в модуль `survey_ui.py`.

```
pyuic5 survey_ui.ui -o survey_ui.py -x
```

`survey_ui.ui` - модуль, который мы создали в **Qt Designer**.

Запустите Qt Designer и посмотрите как выглядит созданная форма:

```
designer.exe survey_ui.ui
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам придется самостоятельно найти Книги и учебные ресурсы по PyQt5 и Qt Designer
если вам это будет интересно.

---

**main_survey.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
# импорт класса Ui_Form из модуля survey_ui.py
from survey_ui import Ui_Form


class myForm(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.book = ''
        self.groupBox_3.hide()
        self.groupBox_4.hide()
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(5, 1)     
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)

    def onClicked(self):
        if not self.lineEdit.text():
            self.groupBox_3.hide()
            self.groupBox_4.hide()
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Информация", "Введите ваше имя!")
            return

        # Выбор учебника            
        if self.radioButton.isChecked() :
            self.book = self.radioButton.text()
        elif self.radioButton_2.isChecked() :
            self.book = self.radioButton_2.text()
        elif self.radioButton_3.isChecked() :
            self.book = self.radioButton_3.text()
        elif self.radioButton_4.isChecked() :
            self.book = self.radioButton_4.text() 
        else:
            self.book = ''
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Информация", "Выберите учебник!")
            return

        # отвечаем на вопрос `Ты пойдёшь в школу?`
        if self.radioButton_5.isChecked() :                   # Да
            self.label_6.setText(f"<b style='color: blue;'>{self.book}</b> у вас первым уроком, "
                                 f"хорошо подготовьтесь.")
            self.groupBox_3.hide()
        elif self.radioButton_6.isChecked() :                 # Нет
            self.groupBox_3.show()
            self.groupBox_4.hide()
            if self.radioButton_7.isChecked() :               # Заболел
                self.label_6.setText(f"Выздоравливайте, "
                                     f"по мере возможности займитесь самоподготовкой.")
            elif self.radioButton_8.isChecked() :             # Устал
                self.label_6.setOpenExternalLinks(True)  
                self.label_6.setText(f'<a href="https://s1.tchkcdn.com/g-vsA4TWjl-pYqkcpxvCRBMw/13/433866/660x0/w/0/5a66bd9c57ce6f0f8bcc99a020470420_razminka_na_rabochem_meste_uprazhneniya_dlya_tekh_kto_rabotayet_za_kompyuterom_2.jpg">Упражнение для снятия усталости.</a>')
            else:
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Ответьте на Вопрос", 
                    "Выберите ответ: Почему ты не пойдешь в школу ?")
                self.groupBox_3.show()                
                self.groupBox_4.hide()
                self.gridLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)                
                return
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Ответьте на Вопрос", "Ты пойдёшь в школу ?")
            self.radioButton_7.setChecked(False)
            self.radioButton_8.setChecked(False)
            return 


        self.label_4.setText(f"Уважаемый <b style='color: red;'>{self.lineEdit.text()}</b>")
        if self.book != "Информатика":
            self.label_5.setText(f"Вот ваша <b style='color: blue;'>{self.book}</b>")
        else:
            self.label_5.setText(f"Учебник <b style='color: blue;'>{self.book}</b> разобрали. "
                                 f"Зайдите завтра.")
            if self.radioButton_6.isChecked() :
                if self.radioButton_7.isChecked() :               # Заболел
                    self.label_6.setText(f"Выздоравливайте, "
                                         f"по мере возможности займитесь самоподготовкой.")
                elif self.radioButton_8.isChecked() :             # Устал
                    self.label_6.setOpenExternalLinks(True)  
                    self.label_6.setText(f'<a href="https://s1.tchkcdn.com/g-vsA4TWjl-pYqkcpxvCRBMw/13/433866/660x0/w/0/5a66bd9c57ce6f0f8bcc99a020470420_razminka_na_rabochem_meste_uprazhneniya_dlya_tekh_kto_rabotayet_za_kompyuterom_2.jpg">Упражнение для снятия усталости.</a>')
            else:            
                self.label_6.setText(f"<b style='color: blue;'>{self.book}</b> у вас первым уроком, <br>"
                                     f"для подготовки воспользуйтесь Интернетом.")
        self.groupBox_4.show()
        self.gridLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = myForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**survey_ui.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'survey_ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(420, 513)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(420, 200))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setVerticalSpacing(10)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(10, -1, 10, -1)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.labelName = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.labelName.setFont(font)
        self.labelName.setObjectName("labelName")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.labelName)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 60))
        self.pushButton.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setAutoRepeatInterval(200)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.groupBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.groupBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.groupBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(410, 80))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 251, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 91, 21))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 40, 91, 21))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 40, 71, 21))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 40, 91, 20))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.groupBox_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.groupBox_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.groupBox_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(410, 80))
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 421, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.radioButton_5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.radioButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_5.setObjectName("radioButton_5")
        self.radioButton_6 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.radioButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_6.setObjectName("radioButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.groupBox_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.groupBox_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.groupBox_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(410, 80))
        self.groupBox_3.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox_3.setObjectName("groupBox_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 291, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.radioButton_7 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_3)
        self.radioButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_7.setObjectName("radioButton_7")
        self.radioButton_8 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_3)
        self.radioButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_8.setObjectName("radioButton_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_3, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_4 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(410, 100))
        self.groupBox_4.setObjectName("groupBox_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_4)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 451, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_4)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 451, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox_4)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 381, 31))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_4, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.labelName.setText(_translate("Form", "Введите Ваше имя: "))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Опубликовать \n"
"результат опроса"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Учебник:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Какой учебник вы выбираете ?"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Математика"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Литература"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Музыка"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Информатика"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Школа:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Ты пойдёшь в школу ?"))
        self.radioButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Да"))
        self.radioButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "Нет"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Почему ты не пойдешь в школу ?"))
        self.radioButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "Заболел"))
        self.radioButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Устал"))
        self.groupBox_4.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Результат опроса:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Уважаемый "))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Возьмите учебник "))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>Математика у вас первым уроком, <br/>хорошо подготовьтесь.</p></body></html>"))
```

---

**survey_ui.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>420</width>
    <height>513</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>420</width>
    <height>200</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <property name="verticalSpacing">
      <number>10</number>
     </property>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>10</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="labelName">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Введите Ваше имя: </string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="enabled">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>140</width>
           <height>60</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="baseSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>10</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Опубликовать 
результат опроса</string>
         </property>
         <property name="autoRepeatInterval">
          <number>200</number>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>410</width>
         <height>80</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="title">
        <string>Учебник:</string>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>251</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Какой учебник вы выбираете ?</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>40</y>
          <width>91</width>
          <height>21</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Математика</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>110</x>
          <y>40</y>
          <width>91</width>
          <height>21</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Литература</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_3">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>210</x>
          <y>40</y>
          <width>71</width>
          <height>21</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Музыка</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_4">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>290</x>
          <y>40</y>
          <width>91</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Информатика</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="0">
      <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>410</width>
         <height>80</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="title">
        <string>Школа:</string>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>421</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Ты пойдёшь в школу ?</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_5">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>50</y>
          <width>82</width>
          <height>17</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Да</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_6">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>50</y>
          <width>82</width>
          <height>17</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Нет</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="3" column="0">
      <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_3">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>410</width>
         <height>80</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="title">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>291</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Почему ты не пойдешь в школу ?</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_7">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>50</y>
          <width>82</width>
          <height>17</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Заболел</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_8">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>50</y>
          <width>82</width>
          <height>17</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Устал</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="4" column="0">
      <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_4">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>410</width>
         <height>100</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="title">
        <string>Результат опроса:</string>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>20</y>
          <width>451</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Уважаемый </string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>40</y>
          <width>451</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Возьмите учебник </string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>60</y>
          <width>381</width>
          <height>31</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Математика у вас первым уроком, &lt;br/&gt;хорошо подготовьтесь.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @WOModerMra что не так?