# Не понимаю почему не сбрасывают я значения радиобаттоны PyQt5 python

Tags: pyqt5, radiobutton

Я начинающий программист, пишу проект, который. задали мне как дз. Код ужасен, не закоментирован. Предупреждаю.

Вообщем, функция ask1_verno это функция, которая воспроизводится, если выбран правильный ответ на 1 вопрос. Функция ask1_neverno та же функция, но если ответ не правильный. Соответственно ask2_verno, ask2_neverno - те же самые функции, но для 2 вопроса. Вся моя конструкция строится на функциях и на "если верный радиобаттон нажат, то - ask1_verno, если нажат не верный радиобаттон, то - ask1_neverno" и на 1 вопросе все нормально, работает, но на 2 - нет. По скольку у меня почему то сохраняются значения радиобаттонов, которые выбрал пользователь с 1 вопроса сразу же без отображения 2 вопроса включается функция - ask2_verno, либо же соответственно ask2_neverno.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(400, 500)

        self.setWindowTitle('Memory Card')   

        self.btn_OK = QPushButton("Ответить", self)
        self.btn_OK.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.verno = QLabel('ПРАВИЛЬНОООО!')
        self.neverno = QLabel('не правильно((')
        self.verno.hide()
        self.neverno.hide()
        self.question = QLabel('Какой национальности не существует?')
        self.varianti = QLabel('Варианты ответов\n↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓')

        self.RadioGroupBox = QGroupBox(None)
        self.RadioGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.rbtn_1 = QRadioButton('Татары')
        self.rbtn_2 = QRadioButton('Чурки')
        self.rbtn_3 = QRadioButton('Евреи')
        self.rbtn_4 = QRadioButton('Уйгуры')
        self.verniy_rbtn1 = QLabel('Чурки')
        self.verniy_rbtn1.hide()
        self.verniy_rbtn2 = QLabel('В 1917 году')
        self.verniy_rbtn2.hide()
        self.RadioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_1)
        self.RadioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_2)
        self.RadioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_3)
        self.RadioGroup.addButton(self.rbtn_4)        

        line = QHBoxLayout(self.RadioGroupBox)               
        line1 = QVBoxLayout()
        line2 = QVBoxLayout()
        line1.addWidget(self.rbtn_1)
        line1.addWidget(self.rbtn_3)
        line2.addWidget(self.rbtn_2)
        line2.addWidget(self.rbtn_4)
        line2.addWidget(self.verniy_rbtn1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        line2.addWidget(self.verniy_rbtn2, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)
        line2.addWidget(self.verno)
        line2.addWidget(self.neverno)
        line.addLayout(line1)
        line.addLayout(line2)


        layout_last = QVBoxLayout(self)  
        layout_last.setSpacing(40)                   
        layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout3 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout4 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout5 = QHBoxLayout()

        layout1.addWidget(self.question, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout3.addWidget(self.RadioGroupBox)                 
        layout5.addWidget(self.btn_OK)
        layout2.addWidget(self.varianti, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        layout_last.addLayout(layout1)
        layout_last.addLayout(layout2)
        layout_last.addLayout(layout3)
        layout_last.addLayout(layout4)
        layout_last.addLayout(layout5)

    def on_click(self):
        def ask1_verno(self):
            self.rbtn_1.hide()
            self.rbtn_2.hide()
            self.rbtn_3.hide()
            self.rbtn_4.hide()
            self.verno.show()
            self.verniy_rbtn1.show()
            self.btn_OK.setText('Следующий вопрос')

        def ask1_neverno(self):
            self.rbtn_1.hide()
            self.rbtn_2.hide()
            self.rbtn_3.hide()
            self.rbtn_4.hide()
            self.neverno.show()
            self.verniy_rbtn1.show()
            self.btn_OK.setText('Следующий вопрос')

        def ask2_verno(self):
            self.rbtn_1.hide()
            self.rbtn_2.hide()
            self.rbtn_3.hide()
            self.rbtn_4.hide()
            self.verno.show()
            self.verniy_rbtn2.show()
            self.btn_OK.setText('Следующий вопрос')

        def ask2_neverno(self):
            self.rbtn_1.hide()
            self.rbtn_2.hide()
            self.rbtn_3.hide()
            self.rbtn_4.hide()
            self.neverno.show()
            self.verniy_rbtn2.show()
            self.btn_OK.setText('Следующий вопрос')


        if self.btn_OK.text() == 'Ответить':
            if self.rbtn_2.isChecked():
                ask1_verno(self)
            elif self.rbtn_1.isChecked() or self.rbtn_4.isChecked() or self.rbtn_3.isChecked():          
                ask1_neverno(self)
        elif self.btn_OK.text() == 'Следующий вопрос':
self.RadioGroup.setExclusive(False)
            self.neverno.hide()
            self.verniy_rbtn1.hide()
            self.verno.hide()
            self.btn_OK.text() == 'Ответить'
            self.rbtn_1.setText('В 1945 году')
            self.rbtn_2.setText('В 666 году')
            self.rbtn_3.setText('В 1917 году')
            self.rbtn_4.setText('В 205645657567 году')
            self.rbtn_1.show()
            self.rbtn_2.show()
            self.rbtn_3.show()
            self.rbtn_4.show()
            if self.rbtn_3.isChecked():
                ask2_verno(self)
            elif self.rbtn_1.isChecked() or self.rbtn_4.isChecked() or self.rbtn_2.isChecked():          
                ask2_neverno(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1440383/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80/1443221#1443221 отвечает на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но буду рад, если найдёт время подправить мой код, чтобы радиобаттоны сбрасывались.

Comment: sorry, ваш код подправить невозможно, его можно только переписать. Попробуйте изучить то, что я вам предложил и вставить в тот код свои данные. Если что-то не получится - зададите новый вопрос и покажите новый код.

Comment: Хорошо. В любом случае большое спасибо!